# Manifest got removed when commited

Tags: android, git, github

We're currently working on a project where we commit our changes to gitHub. I pulled the request from gitHub and did all my changes, but once I press "commit" some files just disappeared.

My manifest file suddenly got removed from the project, or alteast moved to another position and I'm getting the error:

> ERROR: Failed to parse XML in C:*****\AndroidStudioProjects***\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml
>   ParseError at [row,col]:[32,49]
>   Message: expected start or end tag
>   Affected Modules: app

I cannot run the app since it cannot find the manifest file.

All this happend after I tried to sync the ***build.gradle*** file.

I've tried to:

- Revert
- Version Control - My old file - Checkout revision
- Restarted Android Studio

But the manifest.xml is still gone. What can we do to fix this issue?

Comment: Could you check the recent commits that could've caused this on your GitHub repository? Alternatively, you could try with the `git log` command which should list the recent commits.

Comment: @Edric We've checked the recent commits and nothing seems to cause this problem.

All other has the manifest file and so had I, but it suddenly got removed when I pressed the "commit" button. (I did not push it, just commited.)

Comment: Could you check if you've possibly stashed it? Or maybe you've accidentally done a reset?

Comment: @Edric How can I do this? :)